# Not able to use datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

Below is the jade code I am using for implementing a datetimepicker.

But I am getting an error

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

and it is pointing to `datetimepicker` function.

I have already seen many question related to this in stackoverflow. But none is helping. Would be grateful for any help given.

I feel it it is related to the loading of jQuery files only.

Below is the code used:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js') 
    script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js') 
    script(src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js')
    script(src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js')
  body

    link(rel='stylesheet',    href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css')
    block content
    script(src='/javascripts/script.js')

    .container
      .row
        .col-sm-6
          .form-group
             datetimepicker1.input-group.date
              input.form-control(type='text')
              span.input-group-addon
                span.glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar
        script(type='text/javascript').
          $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
          });
```

Comment: Where is your `<DIV/input ID="datetimepicker"></DIV>` and can we see a piece of the rendered html?

Comment: have you tried replacing $ with jQuery? sometimes there are clashes with the $ symbol if you are using more than just jQuery

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery twice?

Comment: forgot to tell, i am just a beginner in this field. So @adrift: which is the one that is actually loading jquery and which is the line i should remove?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets:it is there just under ".form-group". it was showing as commented due to "#". i have removed it.

Comment: Adding the below 2 lines solved the problem:    script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-   with-locales.js')   
      script(src='/javascripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js')